# Why does this SQL query return zero rows?

Tags: sql

I have three tables, `menu_level1`, `menu_level2` and `menu_level3`.

The first table has three columns:

```
id, url, menuname
```

I'm hungarian, our language use accented characters, so I have to make menuname column for accented character menus.

The second and the third tables have these columns:

```
id, url, menuname, relation
```

Relation is necessary, because it shows the relationship among the tables. So, I have a menu system for example:

```
services -> webpage making -> business webpages
```

the rows looks like below:

**menu_level1**

```
url->services
```

**menu_level2**

```
url->webpage making
relation->services
```

**menu_level3**

```
url->business webpages
relation->webpage making
```

I'd like to select from tables with inner join. I use the following code:

```
SELECT 
    menu_leve2.url AS url2, menu_level1.url AS url1 
FROM 
    menu_level2 
INNER JOIN 
    menu_level1 ON 'menu_level2.relation' = 'menu_level1.url'
```

But it returns zero rows. WHY? menu_level2 has rows, where the relation is the same like menu_level2's url.

What is the problem? Why doesn't work this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have enclosed the column names in single quotes, turning them into strings rather than references.  The two strings are not the same, so the comparison is always false.

Try:

```
SELECT menu_level2.url AS url2, menu_level1.url AS url1
FROM menu_level2 INNER JOIN
     menu_level1 
    ON menu_level2.relation = menu_level1.url;
```

If you are learning SQL, I would advise you to use table aliases:

```
SELECT ml2.url AS url2, ml1.url AS url1
FROM menu_level2 ml2 INNER JOIN
     menu_level1 ml1
    ON ml2.relation = ml1.url;
```

The resulting queries are easier to write and to read.

It seems strange to me that `relation` would be equated to `url`.  Without sample data, it is hard to understand whether or not this is correct.  But you should check the `join` conditions to be sure they are what you want.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not working. I get the same result. :)

Comment: Then look at your data.  Maybe there are no matching rows.

Answer (score 0):

You are mention the column names in to single quotes.

```
SELECT 
    menu_leve2.url AS url2, menu_level1.url AS url1 
FROM 
    menu_level2 
INNER JOIN 
    menu_level1 ON menu_level2.relation = menu_level1.url
```

or you can make the alias of the table and call with the reference of alias.

```
SELECT 
    menu_leve2.url AS url2, menu_level1.url AS url1 
FROM 
    menu_level2 ml2,
    menu_level1 ml1
WHERE
    ml2.relation = ml1.url
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is a repeat of Gordon's answer.